# How to use core php function In Symfony framework Twig file

Tags: symfony, twig

I am new with Symfony and I've searched a lot on the net how to use core PHP functions like array functions (in_array , array_combine) , string functions (strpos , strlen) , date functions (date,timestamp),etc.. In Symfony Twig file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, create `Twig/Extension` directory into your bundle. Sample: `AppBundle/Twig/Extension`

Then, create a class for your function name. I create a `JsonDecode` and i use every twig file this function;

```
namespace AppBundle\Twig\Extension;

class JsonDecode extends \Twig_Extension {
    public function getName() {
        return 'twig.json_decode';
    }
    public function getFilters() {
        return array(
            'json_decode' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'jsonDecode')
        );
    }
    public function jsonDecode($string) {
        return json_decode($string);
    }
}
```

Then,

add lines into `services.yml`;

```
twig.json_decode:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\Extension\JsonDecode
    tags:
        - { twig.extension }
```

that's enough.

Comment: Thanks For Help me , I have one query Which Extension i set on JsonDecode  file (php , twig , or other) ?

Comment: so you will create php file undet Twig/Extension what you want function, you will set name it.

Comment: ok, But how to Use That function on twig file because right now it give me below error:
Code:
{{jsonDecode(result.id)}}

Error:
Unknown "jsonDecode" function.

Comment: I also try below Code in Twig File and that give me error.
**code:**    {{result.id|jsonDecode(result.id)}}

**Error**: 

Unknown "json_decode" filter. Did you mean "json_encode"?

Comment: {{ result | json_decode () }} or {{ json_decode(result) }} one of them

Comment: how to register custom extension as a service , Please replay me?

Comment: how to register custom extension as a service , Please replay me because now it give me error Unknown "json_decode" function. so please Help me.

Comment: Below Yml service file Code That I use:
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value
     app.file.twig.extension.class: AppBundle\Twig\Extension\TwigExtension
services:
    app.locale_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
        arguments: ['%kernel.default_locale%']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }

Comment: okay, i edited my comment. you can find new info for services.yml at my comment.

Comment: Thanks Bro for help use but now I get new error Below:

**Error:**
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException: Malformed inline YAML string: { twig.extension } at line 15 (near "- { twig.extension }"). in D:\xampp\htdocs\meopin_2\trunk\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Inline.php:531

Comment: Please help me i try to add custom extension since last one days but almost completed now just error on yml file i get below 
**Error:**

Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException: Malformed inline YAML string: { twig.extension } at line 15 (near "- { twig.extension }"). in D:\xampp\htdocs\meopin_2\trunk\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Inline.php:531 Stack trace: #0

Comment: i think you do not copy-paste than my comment for services.yml lines.  you should write your hands. every tab; 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks for help me and it working very well, now my question is Can i use this custom extension in controller side and How ?, because I need that now to use in back end side

Comment: No, if you need custom function and do you want use it everywhere, you need a service. you will create a service function.

Comment: How to create it please guide me

Comment: this documentation very helper; http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container.html under title to 'Injecting Services/Config into a Service'

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom twig extension that you could use in your twig template.

You can follow the [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html)

Comment: Thanks for help use, now problem is filter not found by symphony so for that  
how to register custom extension class as a service , Please replay me?